# Schedule a job to run in the background ( one time task scheduling using at )

Tags: process, background-process, scheduling, jobs, at

Is it possible to request for a job to be run at a later specifed time in the background?

This is what I have so far,

```
 nohup nice MY_PROGRAM > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null | at 05:23 PM Mon & echo $!
```

However, It echos back a process Id e.g. (18454)
This process ID doesnt actually exist, that is, if run

```
ps
```

This is the process ID that is assigened to that job

```
 18453 pts/2    00:00:00 MY_PROGRAM
```

thats is PID-1 = PID somehow?
Any idea why that happens? or in theres any error in my command?

Comment: Are you looking for something that `cron` does not already handle? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 1):

`at` reads the command to execute from the standard input.

You are not sending the command to execute to `at`. You are executing your command and sending the output of your command to `at`.

Try something like:

```
echo 'nohup nice MY_PROGRAM > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null' | at 05:23
```

The `echo` command will print the string `'nohup nice MY_PROGRAM'` and the `|` will pass it to `at`.

I do not know why do you use `nohup` but probably you do need it as `at` jobs are *not interactive*.

P.S. Note the use of single quotes (`'`) to pass the command to `echo` as a string.